# asp.net how can I pass an object generated dynamically to a non dynamic (specified in UI) user control prior to the userControls Page_Init

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control that I need to pass an object to prior to the onInit call of the user control so that the object can be used to build the user control's content prior to loading of the viewState.

Ideally I need to establish the object somewhere on the page's loading process, then target that userControl's object property to pass the established object to it. This all must occur prior to the OnInit call of the userControl.

I have tried a lot of different things, but here are the most obvious ways that have failed:

1. In the Page's Page_Init() I Create object and pass to the constructed user control, then I try and perform the necessary userControl content binding logic on the Page_InitComplete(). This fails because the userControl doesn't seem to call Page_InitComplete and Page_Init of the UserControl occurs before Page_Init of the Page (so weird)
2. I've attempted to put the UserControl binding logic in the Page_Load() call which does occur after the Page's Page_Init(). However this is too late and viewState has already failed to prepopulate because the proper databinding doesn't exist.
3. I've tried to populate the UserControl's object property in the Page_PreInit. However the UserControl hasn't yet been constructed so the reference to the UserControl on the page is null.

I recognize that I could try and use details found in session or application storage for the user control binding logic but this seems unnecessary. What if someday I got rid of that session or application variables?

Because this is a complex object I'm certain that I can't pass it in to the user control on the UI like <UC:CustomUC propertyName=new ComplexObject()>

What am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing I was missing is that the main purpose of Page_Init() is to (re)generate DYNAMICALLY CREATED CONTROLS. Because my control were not dynamically generated I didn't need to rely on Page_Init.

As such, all of the items of the control are kept via viewstate so I didn't need to repopulate it which was what I was concerned about needing to do. SO this post is more a learning opportunity for me than anyone else.